# Calling [self myMethod] inside a GCD queue

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I am doing some parsing in an asynchronous GCD queue.

I have a method in the class file:

```
- (DirectionType)directionFromString: (NSString*)direction;
```

How do I call this method, or somehow make it useful inside my queue? If I just call `[self directionFromString: [direction name]]` inside the queue I get the following error:

> warning: instance method `directionFromString:` is being used on `Class` which is not in the root class.

Comment: Are you putting a block with this call on the queue from inside a class method?

Comment: What @JoshCaswell said. It looks like you're creating the block inside a class method, in which case `self` will refer to the class and not an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

How did you use the async GCD queue? I tried and it worked without error.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    [self printMethod];
});
```

The implementation:

```
- (void)printMethod {
    NSLog(@"It works!");
}
```

Comment: Hmm, might not be the queue that's an issue here. It's actually inside a block method.